# Dask job hangs on last few tasks

Tags: python, pandas, dask, distributed

I am running transformations on Dask DataFrame and sometimes job hangs on last few tasks.

Job:

1. Read 60 dataframes and set_index('ts', sorted=True)
2. df = dd.concat(dfs, interleave_partitions=True)
3. df = df.map_partitions(lambda pdf: pdf.sort_index()).persist()
4. df = df.repartition(partition_size='4GB')
5. save

ECS Cluster:
[image]

Progress view hangs on last few tasks:
[image]
Do you have idea how to avoid this weird issue?

Comment: Some code or an idea of what your workflow looks like would definitely be useful. We can tell a decent amount from the names of the tasks, but more info about your compute architecture, size of the job, how I/O works, num/sizes of partitions, etc would be helpful. You do have a huge number of tasks. Any chance you could get away with fewer partitions? random failures in a graph this large aren't uncommon, so it will be helpful if we can just make the graph smaller or if we have to work on triage strategies.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added some details. Let me know what else I can provide. As I do concat with interleave_partitions=True I should have smaller partitions to avoid OOM after the concat. Had the same issue even with smaller number of tasks(40k). Is it possible to configure dask to restart long running tasks?